# Micronaut java gradle project can't detect the controller , testing any route the response return Not found

Tags: java, micronaut

Here is the build gradle

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "3.7.9"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.micronaut"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-jackson-databind")
    implementation("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")
    implementation("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    implementation 'net.datafaker:datafaker:1.9.0'
    runtimeOnly("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty")
    runtimeOnly("io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.66.Final")
    runtimeOnly("io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.66.Final")
}

application {
    mainClass.set("com.micronaut.Application")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
}

graalvmNative.toolchainDetection = false
micronaut {
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.micronaut.*")
    }
}
```

Here is the controller implementation

```
package com.micronaut.broker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.micronaut.broker.data.InMemoryStore;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;

@Controller("/symbol")
public class SymbolController {

    private final InMemoryStore inMemoryStore;

    public SymbolController(InMemoryStore inMemoryStore) {
        this.inMemoryStore = inMemoryStore;
    }

    @Get("/")
    public List<Symbol> getAll() {

        return new ArrayList<>(inMemoryStore.getSymbols().values());
    }

    @Get("/hello")
    public String hello() {

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I tried to debug the code but it executed directly with out accessing the breakpoints in the controller

- tried also changes the version and dependencies of the server and the netty server

But everything end with that response when try `http://localhost:8080/symbol/hello` or that `http://localhost:8080/symbol/hello`
it show that error

{
"message": "Not Found",
"_links": {
"self": {
"href": "/symbol/hello",
"templated": false
}
},
"_embedded": {
"errors": [
{
"message": "Page Not Found"
}
]
}
}

Answer (score 2):

First off, I had no trouble running your application with `./gradlew run`.

Not sure how you created it, did you use [Micronaut Launch](https://micronaut.io/launch/), [Micronaut CLI](https://micronaut.io/download/) or via an IDE (IntelliJ and VS Code have plugins)?

Or did you start with the code from one of the many [guides](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/index.html)? For example: [Creating your First Micronaut Application](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/creating-your-first-micronaut-app-gradle-java.html).

If you are running from IntelliJ with Gradle, check out [Using IntelliJ IDEA to Develop Micronaut Applications](https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-intellij-idea-ide-setup-gradle-java.html).

*build.gradle*

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "3.7.9"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.micronaut"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-jackson-databind")
    implementation("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")
//    implementation("javax.inject:javax.inject:1") // Not needed
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    implementation 'net.datafaker:datafaker:1.9.0'
//    runtimeOnly("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty") // Not needed
//    runtimeOnly("io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.66.Final") // Not needed
//    runtimeOnly("io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.66.Final") // Not needed
}

application {
    mainClass.set("com.micronaut.Application")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("17")
}

graalvmNative.toolchainDetection = false
micronaut {
    runtime("netty") // Add
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.micronaut.*")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the eclipse can't read the project as a gradle project so it cannot detect the controller .

Here the steps that worked for me for eclipse users :

- Eclipse → Window → Show View → other → Gradle Tasks

- Then in Gradle Tasks import the project

- Expand the project → Application → double click run

Issue should be solved